# Regex pattern for numbers with dots

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex expression for this

any number then . and again number and .

So this is valid

```
1.3.164.1.2583.15.46
546.598.856.1.68.268.695.5955565
```

but

```
5..........
...56.5656
```

are not valid

I tried patterns like:

```
pattern = "[0-9](\\.[0-9]?*)?*";
pattern = "[0-9](\\.[0-9]?*)?$";
pattern = "[^0-9\\.]";
```

but none of these fulfill my requirement. Please help?

My existing code is

```
String PATTERN="\\d+(\\.\\d+)*";
@Override
public void insertString(int arg0, String arg1, AttributeSet arg2)
{

    if(!arg1.matches(this.PATTERN))
        return;

    super.insertString(arg0, arg1, arg2);
}
```

Comment: I can't use chat, unfortunately.  Can you post the input that doesn't work?

Comment: I am using a common text field named Oldfield allow it to type only the matching patterns. currently it takes only numbers

Comment: Then something else is wrong, you can clearly see that this regex matches the pattern you specified.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this should work:

`(\\d+\\.?)+`

#### Edit

Yep, not clear from the description if a final `.` is allowed (assuming an initial one is *not*).

If not:

`(\\d+\\.?)*\\d+`  or  `\\d+(\\.\\d+)*` (if that seems more logical)

#### Test

```
for (String test : asList("1.3.164.1.2583.15.46",
    "546.598.856.1.68.268.695.5955565", "5..........", "...56.5656"))
    System.out.println(test.matches("\\d+(\\.\\d+)*"));
```

produces:

```
true
true
false
false
```

Comment: that's assuming a period is accepted as the last occurrence in the string, e.g. `12.34.`
You can use `\d+(\.\d+)*`

Comment: its not working. this add $ Symbols and "d" not adding integers

Comment: Afraid you lost me.  What does "'d' not adding integers" mean?

Comment: String PATTERN="\\d+(\\.\\d+)*";                           if(!arg1.matches(this.PATTERN))
 return;                                           super.insertString(arg0, arg1, arg2);

Comment: Can you repost that with formatting and in the form of a question? Why are you using `.find()`? It seems like you're only checking if the string matches.

Comment: In your example `PATTERN` is not the same as `this.PATTERN`. What do you mean by does not take `.`? Is it supposed to match a single dot by itself?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18950/discussion-between-nikhil-and-dmitri)

Answer (score 1):

This one 
`[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)* equivalent to \\d+([.]\\d+)*` is  valid for

> 1.3.164.1.2583.15.46 **,** 546.598.856.1.68.268.695.5955565 **and** 5465988561682686955955565

And this one  `[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)+ equivalent to \\d+([.]\\d+)+` is valid for

> 1.3.164.1.2583.15.46 and 546.598.856.1.68.268.695.5955565 **but not for** 5465988561682686955955565

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking recursive regex here, and my pattern is:

```
pattern = "\\d+.\\d+(?:.\\d+.\\d+)*"
```

Comment: Replace \ with \\ and add \\ before each .

Answer (score 0):

You could match with the following regular expression.

```
(?<![.\d])\d+(?:\.\d+)+(?![.\d])
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/OcJbQ2/4/)

The negative lookarounds are to avoid matching `.1.3.164.1` and `1.3.164.1.`. Including `\d` in the lookarounds is to avoid matching `1.3.16` in `1.3.164.1.`.

Java's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<![.\d])  : negative lookbehind asserts following character is not
              preceded by a '.' or digit
\d+         : match 1+ digits
(?:\.\d+)   : match '.' then 1+ digits in a non-capture group
+           : match the non-capture group 1+ times
(?![.\d])   : negative lookahead asserts preceding character is not
              followed by a '.' or digit
```